# Connectedness ( cardinality and connectedness)

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, cardinals, connectedness

$(X,d)$ metric space and $A\subset X$ and $A$ is connected.
$$ \text{Card}(A) > 2 \implies \text{Card}(A) \geq \text{Card}(\mathbb{R}).$$

How do I prove it ?Waiting for your help?

Comment: If $R$ is $\Bbb R$, the set of real numbers, it’s false: $\Bbb R$ is a connected subset of itself. Do you mean that $\operatorname{card}A\ge\operatorname{card}\Bbb R$?

Comment: You can find a proof in my answer at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/96541/connected-metric-spaces-with-at-least-2-points-are-uncountable

Comment: And [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/239600/is-every-connected-metric-space-with-at-least-two-points-uncountable), [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/504588/proving-that-every-countable-metric-space-is-disconnected), and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/552267/if-x-d-is-a-connected-metric-with-at-least-two-points-prove-it-is-uncountabl).